# WPF Override style in different assembly

Tags: c#, wpf, resourcedictionary

I am trying to make a plugin WPF application that can be referenced on other applications and the latter can change the styles of the former.

My example is based on Xceed's BusyIndicator. I have a style for the BusyIndicator in my plugin WPF app and want the style of that BusyIndicator to be changed on other applications.

Example:

WPF Plugin Application: Let's call it OverrideBusyIndicator. The solution looks like the image below where a MainWindow containing the BusyIndicator exists and the BusyIndicator style is in BusyContextResourceDictionary.xaml

[image]

The content of BusyContextResourceDictionary.xaml is this:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:xceed="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<Style TargetType="{x:Type xceed:BusyIndicator}">
    <Setter Property="BusyContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Margin="4">
                    <TextBlock Text="Downloading Email" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <StackPanel Margin="4">
                        <TextBlock Text="Downloading message 4/10..."/>
                        <ProgressBar Value="40" Height="15"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Button Grid.Column="0" Content="Pause" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0 0 2 0"/>
                        <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Cancel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="2 0 0 0"/>
                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

[image]

I created another solution that will reference my assembly above. Let's call it OverrideBusyIndicator2. This one has no main window and its App.xaml just calls the other OverrideBusyIndicator.MainWindow. I then added a BusyContextResourceDictionary2.xaml that **I EXPECT** to override the style of the BusyIndicator but it does not. Any way I could achieve this behavior?

```
<Application x:Class="OverrideBusyIndicator2.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:xceed="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
         StartupUri="pack://application:,,,/OverrideBusyIndicator;component/MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="BusyContextResourceDictionary2.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

For sample purposes BusyContextResourceDictionary2.xaml will just change the textblock text from "Downloading email" to "Not Downloading email".

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:xceed="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/OverrideBusyIndicator;component/BusyContextResourceDictionary.xaml"/>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

<!--I am using BasedOn to override the BusyContextResourceDictionary.xaml-->

<Style TargetType="{x:Type xceed:BusyIndicator}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type xceed:BusyIndicator}}">
            <Setter Property="BusyContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Margin="4">
                            <TextBlock Text="NOT Downloading Email" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>**
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to see the style for the xceed:BusyIndicator control.  You might need to define the [default style key property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.defaultstylekeyproperty(v=vs.110).aspx) for your control.

Comment: I updated my question. I also searched about the default style key property but I guess that is already set by xceed who created that control which is why I can apply the style in OverrideBusyIndicator.sln (first app above).

Comment: You have two styles with the same target type.  You need to specify a key for one of them and refer to this key in your XAML or use BasedOn attribute.

Comment: Thanks for specifying that. I tried the BasedOn and I'm getting crazy why this is not yet working (see edit).